# Limiting jQuery's autocomplete when there are 3 or more characters typed

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery's autocomplete widget like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});

</script>

<p>Search term is: <span id="demo"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want to limit it to only suggesting values if there are 3 or more characters in the autocomplete form. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the autocomplete with the minLength option specified:

```
$(".selector").autocomplete({ minLength: 3 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the minLength like this:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({minLength: 3, source: tags});
```